# How to replace all characters after dash with space in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector :

```
v= c("abc_cdef", "ab_ce.ef")
```

I want to get the following vector:

```
v=c("abc", "ab")
```

I tried the following code, but was unsuccessful.

```
gsub("^._$","",v)
```

What regular expression should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
gsub("(.*)_.*$","\\1",v)
# [1] "abc" "ab"
```

Comment: why not `gsub('_.*', '', v)`

Comment: Ya, that's the obvious/better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `strsplit()`

```
sapply(strsplit(v, '_'), '[', 1) 
[1] "abc" "ab"
```

Comment: This also works great. However, I am quite interested in understanding the use of '[' in this code. I am not able to figure out what the function of '[' is in this case.

Comment: `strsplit()` produces a list, check the output of  `strsplit(v, '_')`. We can consequently use `sapply` to traverse over the result and apply `[1]` to each sublist selecting the first element.  It would be the same as calling `[1]` on each sublist, ie `strsplit(v, '_')[[1]][1]` and `strsplit(v, '_')[[2]][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('_.+$', '', v)
# [1] "abc" "ab"  "abc"
```